# How to set different NetBeans IDE Output link colors for 'warnings' and 'errors'

Tags: c++, colors, ide

my compilation results using NetBeans C++ IDE usually show one or a few error links immersed in a big number of warning links. It becomes tedious and difficult to locate the error links in the middle of the warnings forest.
I have not found any way to assign different colors to such links, in order to immediately visually locate just the errors, click, solve the related issue and get rid of a successful compilation.
I have tried playing with Tools > Options > Miscellaneous then Output tab and setting 'link color' cyan and 'important link color' red, but this does not fix the problem.
Is it possible to get error links red and warning links green for example ?
Many thanks in advance,
Marco

Comment: I don't know NetBeans but usually most IDEs provide the possibility to Show Errors Only. It is not C++ or Color related question.

Comment: Thanks a lot, up to now I can't find such option in NetBeans IDE. I will update this post if I find a way.